# Close All Other DIVs and Positioning of hidden DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have created a simple 2 step accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/WkuMg/1/

What i would like to know is, have i used the correct jQuery to ensure that when a `heading` DIV is clicked, the following `content` DIV is expanded AND all other `content` DIVs close.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".heading").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.next(".content").slideToggle();
  $this.parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  return false;
});
```

Also, looking at the fiddle above, you can see i have tried to position the `content` DIV's to the right of the `heading` DIVs and at the top. I have used some CSS for this:

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
.heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    background: GREY;    
    width: 30%;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Specifically the use of absolute and top: -2px;

Thanks

Comment: what is your question???

Comment: @Neel - the question is, have i gone about this the 'correct' way, or is there a better/more efficient/cross-browser compatabile way of achieving the outcome?

Comment: A better place to ask this might be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works and makes sense, you may improve by putting some delay in the apparition of the new content, for a nicer transition http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/2/

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $this.next(".content").slideToggle();
}, 200);
```

You also can work with classes, so you do not have to sort your HTML this way and pack all headers in one part, all content on the other.

Comment: thanks, is there any way for Contact Us to always show when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah You did good. But it would be better. Add a class to container and check the container class and do a slide function. `if` statement will use for remove same slide repeat again.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".heading").click(function () {
            if ($(this).next(".content").hasClass("folded")){
                $(".content").slideUp();
                 $(".unfolded").toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded");
               $(this).next(".content").toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").slideDown();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Here the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/3/)

Updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkuMg/4/)**

Comment: thanks, is there any way for Contact Us to always show when the page is loaded?